# Ecto put_assoc why preload and why require id

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm getting rather confused about Ecto when it comes to adding a new association to an existing model. Let's say I have some discussion board where users can like a post, and I have the following models:

```
  schema "discussion_items" do
    many_to_many :likes, XXX.Tag, join_through: "discussion_items_likes"
    timestamps()
  end

  schema "likes" do
    belongs_to :user, XXX.User
    timestamps()
  end
```

Now lets say I have an existing `DiscussionItem` and I want to add a like association to this, here's what Im trying (simplified):

```
user = Repo.one(User)
discussion_item = Repo.one(from d in DiscussionItem, preload [:likes])

like_changeset = Like.changeset(%Like{})
                     |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:user,   user)
changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(discussion_item) 
                |>  Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:likes, [like_changeset])

Ecto.update!(changeset)
```

What I am finding is that this will create the Like and the association correctly the first time but then complain afterwards that I need additional information in the form of some id:

> you are attempting to change relation :likes of XXX.DiscussionItem,
>   but there is missing data
>
> If you are attempting to update an existing entry, please make sure
>   you include the entry primary key (ID) alongside the data.
>
> If you have a relationship with many children, at least the same N
>   children must be given on update. By default it is not possible to
>   orphan embed nor associated records, attempting to do so results in
>   this error message.

So here's the things that confuse me (there are a few):

1. This error message seems to suggest that in order to update one associated item, I need to provide a change set with ALL items including the one that changed. This seems nuts, so I'm guessing I'm reading this wrong.
2. I don't want to update the likes association -- I want to add one. Is put_assoc the wrong choice here?
3. Do I really need to preload the likes just to insert an item? Even on update I don't want to load the whole collection of associations to change one.
4. Do I need to load `User` and `Dicussion_item` to add a like here?

Comment: Seems that I found the answer is that put_assoc requires all existing items plus the one I want to add ran through change sets themselves. This seems highly inefficient so hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: Why are you using `many_to_many` for likes and discussion items? Shouldn't a like count for only a single discussion item at a time?

Comment: I have several things I want to like, discussion items is just one of them so there will be several join tables. It's really beside the point anyway, what I really want to know is how to insert a new item in a many to many relationship without loading the world, the example above is not so important

Comment: [this](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.6/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3-join-schema-example) is probably the best thing to do. It is a little more verbose, but I think it is worth it for how simple everything becomes.

Comment: Cheers Justin, shame I do have to do this but thats much better that the alternative.

Answer (score 6):

> This error message seems to suggest that in order to update one associated item, I need to provide a change set with ALL items including the one that changed. This seems nuts, so I'm guessing I'm reading this wrong.

Yes you need to preload. From the `put_assoc` docs:

> This function requires the association to have been preloaded in the changeset struct. Missing data will invoke the :on_replace behaviour defined on the association.

The example given in the docs:

```
# We can associate at any time post and tags together using changesets
post
|> Repo.preload(:tags) # Load existing data
|> Ecto.Changeset.change() # Build the changeset
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:tags, [tag]) # Set the association
|> Repo.update!
```

> I don't want to update the likes association -- I want to add one. Is put_assoc the wrong choice here?

`put_assoc` is OK here only if you don't mind preloading all the existing `likes`.  If you want to avoid the preload, then a [Join Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3-join-schema-example) looks like the best option.

> Do I really need to preload the likes just to insert an item? Even on update I don't want to load the whole collection of associations to change one.

For the convenience of using `put_assoc` you'll need to preload.
The alternative is to use a [Join Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3-join-schema-example), allowing you to explicitly insert/update the relationship independently of the entity either side.

> Do I need to load User and Dicussion_item to add a like here?

No, you only need the IDs.
You can construct the `Like` changeset with the `user_id` field populated in the params.

Similarly, with a `DiscussionItemLikes` join schema, you can set the `like_id` and `discussion_item_id`.

[Ecto.Multi](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#content) Might be a clean way to create a `%Like{}` and a `%DiscussionItemLike{}` in a single transaction.

```
Multi.new()
|> Multi.insert(insert_like_changeset(params))
|> Multi.insert(insert_discussion_item_like_changeset(params))
|> Repo.transaction()
```